# Visualizing shaded region in Klein bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology, klein-bottle

Regargind the Klein bottle $K$ as its identification space, I want to know what is the subspace of $K$ obtained by identifying the outer edges of the shaded region of the figure.

[image: Klein bottle regarded as its identification]

The main reason I want to visualize this, is because I want to find a map from the punctured torus to Klein bottle. And I am regarding punctured torus as figure eight.
This is exercise (12.12) from Greenberg & Harper's book, An introduction to algebraic topology.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help? I used the visualization [here](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/PuVyyKky)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess so! Thank you very much. What I can visualize is that it is like the figure eight which is torus minus a point so I'd suppose the function is the embbedding but the book says it is not the embedding map

Comment: @Yeipi Yeah I saw that exercise. I am not quite understanding what map does the author talking about